# View on Many To Many Tables

Tags: mysql, view

I have these tables :
`TBL_PERSONS` - a table for persons
`TBL_SPORTS` - a table for sports like football , basketball , tennis and ...
`TBL_PERSON_SPORT` - a table for any person's sports

for example Jo can play Football , and Basketball
I want to create a VIEW on persons and their sports.
something like this:

```
Jo|Football,Basketball
Jack|Football,Tennis
```

how should I write such VIEW?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want them to be a comma-separated list, that is the function of the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function.  Substitute the correct names of your columns in place of `name`, `person_id`, `sport_id`, etc...

```
CREATE VIEW PERSON_SPORTS AS
(
SELECT
  p.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.sport_name) AS sports
FROM
  TBL_PERSONS p
  LEFT JOIN TBL_PERSON_SPORT sp ON p.person_id = sp.person_id
  JOIN TBL_SPORTS s ON sp.sport_id = s.sport_id
GROUP BY p.name
);
```

The above won't be very useful for joining against though, if you need to be able to separate out sports from the comma-separated list. Consider also just wrapping the ungrouped list in a view as:

```
CREATE VIEW PERSON_SPORTS AS
(
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  p.name,
  s.sport_name AS sport
FROM
  TBL_PERSONS p
  LEFT JOIN TBL_PERSON_SPORT sp ON p.person_id = sp.person_id
  JOIN TBL_SPORTS s ON sp.sport_id = s.sport_id
);
```

This will produce one row per sport, containing the person's name and sport name, where the person is duplicated as many times as needed for each sport.